# Am I eligible for a Bluecard if both university and degree are H+, but not directly related?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I can find in the Anabin database both university and the degree listed as H+. The fact is that the Anabin database doesn't connect one with the other.

This [article](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/jobs/recognition/academic-qualifications/) from Germany's Federal Government states the following:

> The two print-outs of the positive results for the university and the degree can then be used together as proof of equivalency.

Comment: What do you mean by "the degree"?  You are not looking for "Physics", you are looking for "Physics from University College London" (substituting whatever degree and university is applicable).

Comment: @MartinBonner, Clarifying: at the Anabin database you can seach independently for a degree OR a institution. 
Let's say I've found the "University College London" rated as H+ as well as "Physics" degree, but this degree is not connected to the "University College London". Is this a problem?

Comment: Was it a problem? Did it work out?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to find both (degree and university) in one data set. It is totaly sufficient to find both in separate searches.